# Open Beta Test on Google Play: Google Play Purchases are not supported in your country

Tags: android, google-play

I am currently running an open beta test for my app on Google Play.
Some people have already installed it, however a friend from Chile (Play Store account country also set to Chile) was unable to install the app on his phone.
He would get this error message:

> Google Play purchases are not supported in your country. Unfortunately you will not be able to complete purchases.

The app does not include any purchases. Also, Chile is not listed as a country where purchases are not supported in the first place.
Is app-testing not available in Chile?
Or is this something in my app (permission?) that prevents the app from being available in Chile?

No idea what’s going here, any help is appreciated

[image: android phone fails to install app]

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. Was able to bypass it and install the app when used a VPN with a specific location (Germany in my case) and clearing the data of Google Play Store package.

Comment: Thanks! Weird thing is, this user attempted to download the App from within Germany, on a German WiFi Network with a German SIM card. However, the Play Store Account is Chilean.